# How to use tommath in a Tcl extension

Tags: tcl, bignum

I'm building a Tcl extension in c that needs to create new bignum Tcl_Objs (using `Tcl_NewBignumObj`), which takes an `mp_int` (libtommath's type).  My extension (by default) calls Tcl's API through its stubs interface.

I include `tclTomMath.h`, and call `Tcl_TomMath_InitStubs(interp, TCL_VERSION)` in my extension's `_Init`.  I'm not linking to an external libtommath (I want to use the version in the Tcl library that my extension will be loaded into).  I don't define `TCL_NO_TOMMATH_H`, and include `tcl.h` before `tclTomMath.h`.

I haven't been able to find a single trace of any code that actually successfully does this.  I read all the pages on the Tcl wiki that appeared to be relevant but left with more confusion than I started with.

My question is: what is the correct, idiomatic way for a stubs-enabled extension to create the `mp_int` argument that is passed to `Tcl_NewBigNumObj`?  I also need to perform some minimal arithmetic on the `mp_int` before handing it to `Tcl_NewBigNumObj`, outside the range of `Tcl_WideInt`, so relying on the `mp_int` defined by `tclTomMath.h` if `TCL_NO_TOMMATH_H` is defined is not enough.

My Tcl sources (recent 8.7) do not install `tommath.h` by `make install` (Linux).  If I don't copy it manually to the install headers location, compilation fails because `tclTomMath.h` tries to include it.  If I do copy it, compilation succeeds, but loading my extension fails with missing symbols like `undefined symbol: mp_error_to_string`.  `mp_error_to_string` does not appear to be in the subset of the tommath API that the Tcl fork's stub interface exposes.  Is reporting generic error messages best the caller can do in this situation?

Sneaky bonus question: what would be the portable, idiomatic way to load the value -1-(2**64-1) (thanks CBOR...) into that `mp_int`?

Comment: This is only a comment, not even an attempt of a partial answer, but as for missing `tommath.h`, this has bitten others: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktview/4663e0636f7a24b9363e67c7a3dd25e9e495be17. These cases could be fixed by removing dependencies on LTM symbols. Check [TIP 538](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/538.md) and consider filing a ticket. Now that Tcl 9 is around the corner, this is an important case to be covered.

Comment: ... and from what I understand, for doing computations using LTM types, an extension must now add LTM as an explicit dependency. The tclconfig machinery should have support for it, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks, that ticket and TIP confirm that my use case is fatally broken - there isn't a clean way to make it work without adding the requirement that users of my extension (rl_json in this case) arrange a suitable libtommath on their build system. Normally I would tightly couple an external dependency like that using a git submodule, but it's already a fight to keep rl_json building on Windows, adding a cmake-built internal dependency to that fight isn't feasible. I'll have to hack around it by building the bignum stringrep and calling `Tcl_EvalObjv` on an `expr` in place of `Tcl_NewBigNumObj`.

Comment: Maybe `Tcl_ExprObj` would be more helpful? That's what `expr` calls (when not compiled out entirely).